# How to create Planner Task with checklist item through Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Planner Task including a couple of checklist items. The  checklist items are part of the task details, but unlike the description field, the checklist items are a list of item with a unique element name like the element samples 14680 and 49286 below.

How can I create such a list for a task through the API?

```
"checklist": {
        "14680": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
            "isChecked": true,
            "title": "Element 2",
            "orderHint": "8586819525[x",
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": null,
                    "id": "a275ad83-babe-437e-a62b-e4f4e738fd7b"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-02-26T14:11:40.2829359Z"
        },
        "49286": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "Element 1",
            "orderHint": "8586819526571539898P;",
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": null,
                    "id": "a275ad83-babe-437e-a62b-e4f4e738fd7b"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-02-26T14:11:28.3392169Z"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can do that at least by doing it in 2 steps:

- Create the task 1st, using `POST /planner/tasks` (doc available [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_tasks?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365))
- Then edit the created task details using `PATCH /planner/tasks/<id>/details` ([doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannertaskdetails_update?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365))

This latest method has a `checklist` in its body like in this example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/gcrYAaAkgU2EQUvpkNNXLGQAGTtu/details
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 857
If-Match: W/"JzEtVGFzayAgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAWCc="

{
  "previewType": "noPreview",
  "references": {
    "http%3A//developer%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerExternalReference",
      "alias": "Documentation",
      "previewPriority": " !",
      "type": "Other"
    },
    "https%3A//developer%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom/en-us/graph/graph-explorer":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerExternalReference",
      "previewPriority": "  !!",
    },
    "http%3A//www%2Ebing%2Ecom": null
  },
  "checklist": {
    "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
      "title": "Update task details",
      "ischecked": true
    },
    "d280ed1a-9f6b-4f9c-a962-fb4d00dc50ff":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
      "isChecked": true,
    },
    "a93c93c5-10a6-4167-9551-8bafa09967a7": null
  }
}
```

If you have a look to the `plannerChecklistItems` documentation, you will see that the checklist item's ID is a client generated ID:

> Properties of an Open Type can be defined by the client. In this case,
> the client should provide GUIDs as properties and their values must be
> checklistItem objects. Example is shown below. To remove an item in
> the checklist, set the value of the property to null.

So you have to generate your own IDs and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.