# Add Planner Task with checklist

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a new task with a checklist in it.

I read [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003261/how-to-create-planner-task-with-checklist-item-through-graph-api) that I need to do this in two steps;
1. Create the task
2. `PATCH` the task, adding checklist items.

When trying to `PATCH` to add tasks, it doesn't add anything. It only edits existing values, like "title". I cannot find any way or documentation to `PUT` details, or create them on initial `POST` when creating the task.

Anyone know how to do this?

**POST — Creating new task:**

```
URI: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks
Content-Type : application/json

RAW:
{
  "planId": "{plan_id}",
  "bucketId": "{bucket_id}",
  "title": "Here is a task",
  "checklist": {
    "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
      "title": "Task details",
      "ischecked": true
    },
    "d280ed1a-9f6b-4f9c-a962-fb4d00dc50ff":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem"
    }
  }
}
```

Response: Body, 201 success:

```
BODY:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#planner/tasks/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"…ETag…\"",
    "planId": "{plan_id}",
    "bucketId": "{bucket_id}",
    "title": "Here is a task",
    "orderHint": "8586523326629295130",
    "assigneePriority": "",
    "percentComplete": 0,
    "startDateTime": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2019-02-04T09:57:02.5480677Z",
    "dueDateTime": null,
    "hasDescription": false,
    "previewType": "automatic",
    "completedDateTime": null,
    "completedBy": null,
    "referenceCount": 0,
    "checklistItemCount": 0,
    "activeChecklistItemCount": 0,
    "conversationThreadId": null,
    "id": "{task_id}",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "displayName": null,
            "id": "{UID}"
        }
    },
    "appliedCategories": {},
    "assignments": {}
}
```

Also tried putting `checklist` block inside a `details` block, and get exact same result.

```
"details": {
  "checklist": { … }
}
```

**PATCH — Updating existing task:**

```
URI: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{task_id}

HEADERS:
If-Match : W/"…ETag…"
Content-type : application/json

RAW:
{
  "title": "New title",
  "checklist": {
    "95e27074-6c4a-447a-aa24-9d718a0b86fa":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
      "title": "Update task details",
      "ischecked": true
    },
    "d280ed1a-9f6b-4f9c-a962-fb4d00dc50ff":{
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem"
    }
  }
}
```

Response: Empty, 204 success. Title is changed, but no new checklist items.

Comment: Without seeing your code, the payload, and the response you're getting back, it isn't possible to answer your question. If you could edit your question and provide this additional context, the community is likely able to help you out.

Comment: The codes are basically the same as in the linked article, and the article(s) they link. Added here too now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the details at the same time you're creating the task. The [`plannerTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [`plannerTaskDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertaskdetails?view=graph-rest-1.0) are distinct objects. Furthermore, the [`details` property of a `plannerTask` is read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships).

You need to first [create a `plannerTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0) and then [update it's associated `plannerTaskDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertaskdetails-update?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I have tried `plannerTaskDetails` previously, but got an error. I copied the example request (from your last link) and attempted to use that, placing appropriate task `id` in the URL and a fresh `ETag` in the header. Using the example give me an error saying `The property 'ischecked' does not exist on type 'microsoft.taskServices.plannerChecklistItem'`. Removing that, I get an error saying `The If-Match header contains an invalid value.`.

Comment: Are you getting the `@odata.etag` from the `/tasks/{id}` or the `/tasks/{id}/details`?

Comment: No I did not. Didn't know they were different. I got the `@odata.etag` tag from `/tasks/{id}/details` and patched to it, as you suggested. It gave me an error saying `"ExternalReference does not have any properties specified."` — which is kind of misleading since it was actually just that I didn't notice my second checklist item did not have a title specified (thinking of `"references"` as _the_ `ExternalReference`). It works now, thank you.

Comment: The property ischecked is the wrong case, it should be isChecked